# Doctrine 2 join table bug?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have two entities, $staff and $pub, and a join table $staffPub. I can save and use $staff and $pub and when I manually populate the $staffPub database table, the relationships all work. The problem is, if I try to persist a $staffPub relation I get the following notices and the row is not committed:

**Notice**:  Undefined index: rmcode in **..../Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php** on line **491**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: pubofficeid in **..../Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php** on line **491**
42

Before I added the @JoinColumn annotation, the $staffPub entities persisted without a problem.

```
class StaffPub {
/**
 * @ManyToOne (targetEntity="Hs_Profile_Publication", inversedBy="staffPubRelation", cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="rmcode", referencedColumnName="rmcode")
 */
private $publication;

/**
 * @ManyToOne (targetEntity="Hs_Profile_Staff", inversedBy="staffPubRelation", cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="pubofficeid", referencedColumnName="pubofficeid")
 */
public $staff;

.... etc ...
```

Both Staff and Pub have ids 'id'. When I set referencedColumnName above to 'id', it does not throw the notices. So, the question is, how do I define 'pubofficeid' and 'rmcode', in Staff and Pub respectively, as ids? If I simply add @Id I get the following error when trying to persist the object:

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

thrown in Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 131.

So it boils down to the following question: how do you persist an object with multiple @Ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the ID of StaffPub? Are you sure this isn't OneToOne? The naming of inversedBy suggests it.

Comment: /**
     * @Id
     * @Column (type="integer", length=11, name="id")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id = null;

Comment: the above is the id of StaffPub - sorry about the formatting. A staff member can have many publications and a publication can have many staff(authors). Why does the naming of inversedBy suggest a oneToOne relationship?